# node.js Facebook SDK OAuthException

Tags: node.js, facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth

I want to create a server with node.js to cache data like public page feed from Facebook graph API. I need this, because I wanted to make an Android app which pulls posts from a Facebook page. The app secret should not be used inside a app which can be decompiled, therefore I must have an dedicated application server

**UPDATE:**
I'm now trying to use Criso's [FBgraph](https://github.com/criso/fbgraph).

Example:

```
var graph = require('fbgraph');
    // pass it in as part of the url 

    graph.get("/4" + "?access_token=appID|appSecret", function(err, res) {

        // returns the post id
        console.log(res); // { id: xxxxx}
    });
```

returns:

```
{ name: 'Mark Zuckerberg', id: '4' }
```

But I need to retrieve feed for a page. I can't use the {pageid} in the URL like: https://www.facebook.com/{pagename}-{pageid}/ returns this error *"Some of the aliases you requested do not exist"* the page is made and assgigned to the app and hasn't been published yet, because I'm testing if it works. Documentation tells me I need a page access code which requires me to login which is not an option.

Also, is there a better way to do this? I'm thinking is *"node.js + NoSQL + facebook Node.js SDK"* faster than *"Apache + NoSQL + PHP facebook SDK"* for caching results?

Comment: What do you mean by _“{appname}-{pageid}”_? Page URLs don’t have app ids in them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use, another library other than tenorviol's node.js, this havn't been updated in 6 years and their should be a lot of issues, and according to this by the repo owner this is not an active project https://github.com/tenorviol/node-facebook-sdk/issues/11

**Suggestions**

Since you're using graph API

https://www.npmjs.com/package/fbgraph

https://www.npmjs.com/package/fb

**Update for second part**

You should look at this to get public feed of a page

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.8/page/feed

but even then it's not possible to access the feed without an access token

eg : 
https://graph.facebook.com/SmashBalloon/feed?access_token=APP-ID|APP-SECRET

Comment: I have edited the post, I'm using fbgraph now. Could you relook at my question please?